# Division using dict values unwanted rounding

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, floating-point

Edit: I found my problem =X turns out that I accidentally included a value from another iterator which caused a static value in the operation. My bad.

Question: Do I delete the question or leave it?

I am trying to write a script that reads values off a nested dictionary, and then performing a division operation and returning it as a key: value pair within the nested dictionary.

So I start off with this:

```
main_dict = {nested: {first_number: int,
                      second_number: int}

             nested1: {first_number: int,
                       second_number: int}
             ...
             }
```

What I want to get is:

```
main_dict = {nested: {first_number: int,
                      second_number: int
                      wanted_number: float}

             nested1: {first_number: int,
                       second_number: int
                       wanted_number: float}
             ...
             }
```

What is did was:

```
for nested in main_dict:
    main_dict[nested]['wanted_number'] = float(main_dict[nested]['first_number'])
                                         / float(main_dict[nested]['second_number'])
```

So for example, first_number = 11, second_number = 15, I should get

```
main_dict[nested]['wanted_number'] = 0.733...
```

But instead I get

```
main_dict[nested]['wanted_number'] = 1.0
```

So far I have tried to use: **from_future** import division, numpy's true_division, which are both supposed to be redundant as I am using Python 3.4.

The output type is float(), and I have tried to explicitly convert the values to float() before division, and after division. I have also tried one term being float() and the other being int(). I have also tried using the decimal module with getcontext().prec = 6.

Is this a characteristic of performing functions, or perhaps the way the values are pointed to a bin?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no such rounding.

Confirm that the numbers you are dividing really are different by printing them out in the `for` loop.

You are correct, in Python3 you don't need any magic to get float division. Not even `float()` is necessary

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 11/15
0.7333333333333333
```

You haven't shown how the dict is constructed. Make sure you're working with distinct sub-dictionaries and not references to the same sub-dictionary or something.

Run it in the REPL to show us what you are seeing.

```
>>> main_dict = {'nested': {'first_number': 11,
...                       'second_number': 15},
...              'nested1': {'first_number': 3,
...                        'second_number': 4}
...              }
>>> 
>>> for nested in main_dict:
...     main_dict[nested]['wanted_number'] = main_dict[nested]['first_number'] / main_dict[nested]['second_number']
... 
>>> main_dict
{'nested1': {'wanted_number': 0.75, 'second_number': 4, 'first_number': 3}, 'nested': {'wanted_number': 0.7333333333333333, 'second_number': 15, 'first_number': 11}}
```

Comment: I checked by calling the entire main_dict and manually checking the numbers. That was how I spotted the error. I also called main_dict[nested]['first_number'], main_dict[nested]['second_number'] and main_dict[nested]['wanted_number'] to check all the types and numbers. wanted_number returns float and 1.0. I also just checked and 15/15 within the script got me 0.0 so I am really really puzzled

Comment: I think you're looking for the bug in the wrong place. It's somewhere else in your code. Post the shortest fragment that exhibits this bug so we can replicate it